# Generating Adjacency List in NetworkX - How to Include Previous Nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

According to the [NetworkX documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.adjlist.generate_adjlist.html), the function `generate_adjlist()` generates an adjacency list shown below:

```py
>>> G = nx.lollipop_graph(4, 3)
>>> for line in nx.generate_adjlist(G):
...     print(line)
0 1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6
```

However, I notice that the adjacency list do not include the nodes that were linked previously. For example, if you look at row three (2 3), it does not include 0 even though at row one (0 1 2 3), 0 links to node 2.

How do I include the previous nodes which were omitted?

Comment: What is wrong with this question for it to be closed? I think the question couldn't be any clearer.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) cc @Marko

Comment: The edit queue is now full, but that it is a pretty simple edit.

Comment: @desertnaut The picture has been replaced by a text, please open the question to potential answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only applies to undirected graphs. By definition in an adjacency list edges that have already been mentioned do not need to be repeated. When creating a graph, if you were to give over a file that had repeating connections, they would simply be ignored as they are redundant. Your option is to create your own function that lists all the nodes, irrespectively of the fact that they were already mentioned. It would look something like this (code shamelessly modified from the original [`generate_adjlist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/readwrite/adjlist.html#generate_adjlist) code):

```py
def generate_adjlist_with_all_edges():
     for s, nbrs in G.adjacency():
        line = str(s) + delimiter
        for t, data in nbrs.items():
                line += str(t) + delimiter
        yield line[: -len(delimiter)]

G = nx.lollipop_graph(4, 3)
for line in generate_adjlist_with_all_edges(G):
    print(line)
> 0 1 2 3
  1 0 2 3
  2 0 1 3
  3 0 1 2 4
  4 5 3
  5 4 6
  6 5
```